# Is IAzureClientFactory<ServiceBusClient>.CreateClient() creating a singleton?

Tags: azureservicebus

I'm implementing an AzureBusServiceClient and i'm asking if with this configuration below :

[image]

And an example of injection:

[image]

If i have 3 processors who does "var client = serviceBusClientFactory.CreateClient("Name1");",
will i have a new instance each time?
Or only one instance is created and retrieved for other calls?

Thank you and sorry for my english :)

Ihave tried for now the singleton approach but i prefer this approach with the factory to handle multiple serviceClientBus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any registration that uses the builder from `AddAzureClients` is a singleton, Service Bus included.

For those that are curious about the details, the [AddServicebusClient](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/main/sdk/servicebus/Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus/src/Compatibility/ServiceBusClientBuilderExtensions.cs#L20) call invokes [AzureClientFactoryBuilder.RegisterClientFactory](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/main/sdk/extensions/Microsoft.Extensions.Azure/src/AzureClientFactoryBuilder.cs#L183), which manipulates the service collection.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and the underlying details